# exercise 10.6.2.d from Zorich‘s book

Tags: taylor-expansion

[exercise 10.6.2.d][1]

I’m trying to solve this problem but have no clue how to solve it. This problem follows the section about Taylor’s formula and the study of extrema.
[1]:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeDmg.jpg

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please do not post links to images. Use MathJax to format your equations: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference See also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question on how to ask a good question.